# How to get specific ID when hovering the td's in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I should be getting a unique timecard_id_overtime when hovering the specific td's but I always get the last id in the while loop. I tried using id instead of class but this didn't work either. Many thanks.

```
<?php include "../db_connection302.php" ; ?>
<?php

         echo"<tr>" ;
         echo"<th class='leave-heading'>Particular </th>" ;
         echo"</tr>" ;


         // GENERATING ALL PENDING ATTENDANCE FOR APPROVAL 
         $query  = "SELECT * FROM ".$_SESSION['$company_code']."_tms WHERE  status = 'Pending' AND (particular = 'Log In' || particular = 'Log Out' || particular = 'Log In/Out' || particular = 'OB' || particular = 'Offsetting' ) ";
         $result_approval = mysqli_query($connection302,$query) or die(mysql_error());
         while($row_approval = mysqli_fetch_array($result_approval))  { 

         echo "<tr>" ;
         echo "<td class='reason'>".$timecard_id_overtime = $row_approval['timecard_id']."</td>" ;
         echo "</tr>" ;

             }

?>  

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>


     var timecard_id = '<?php  echo $timecard_id_overtime  ; ?>' ;   


     $(document).ready(function() {


             $('.reason').hover(function() {

                 alert(timecard_id) ;


             });



         });



 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` loop you are overwriting the same value `$timecard_id_overtime` each iteration of the loop so it will always be the last value when the loop completes.

The values of `$timecard_id_overtime` will be overwritten each time.

```
//first iteration
//$timecard_id_overtime is set to 1

//second iteration
//$timecard_id_overtime is set to 2

//third iteration
//$timecard_id_overtime is set to 3
```

...and so on.

One way to achieve your goal is to set the id with the `<td>` for each loop so the correct id is associated with the correct element. You can set that id as an attribute of the `<td>` element instead of a PHP variable. Then JQuery can get that value easily.

```
...
PHP
...
 while($row_approval = mysqli_fetch_array($result_approval))  { 

     echo "<tr>" ;
     echo "<td class='reason' timecard_id='".$row_approval['timecard_id']."'></td>" ;
     echo "</tr>" ;

         }
...
Javascript
...
 $(document).ready(function() {

         $('.reason').hover(function() {
             alert($(this).attr('timecard_id')) ;
         });
     });
...
...
```